# How to reset a Script?

Tags: c#, unity

Is there a way where I can make the script restore its condition to that before I hit play? Should I create a new copy of the original script every time instead?

Comment: You mean, reset its parameters to the ones specified in the declaration, rather than the altered values shown in the inspector?

Comment: @Draco18s Exactly.